# How to check in MySQL whether the result of one SELECT contains another SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I have tables

```
CREATE TABLE one (
  op INT,
  value INT
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE two (
  tp INT,
  value INT
);
```

Now I want to get all `op` values for which the set of `value`s for the `op` contains all `value`s for a given `tp`.

I would write this as:

```
SELECT op FROM one AS o1 WHERE (
  (SELECT value FROM one AS o2 WHERE o1.op = o2.op)
  CONTAINS ALL
  (SELECT value FROM two WHERE tp=<specific-value>)
)
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find such a `CONTAINS ALL` operator and nothing which would be close that.

Table `one` contains 50M entries, table `two` contains 1M entries. On average, there are 20 different `values` for a single `op` and `tp`.

Comment: Can you please give the exact SQL which you have in mind?

Comment: You can use a INNER JOIN/[... WHERE ... ALL(SELECT ..)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html) here?  Or do i mis something obvious? See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Agree with Raymond about sample data. @RaymondNijland, `ALL (SELECT` is used to compare a value against all possible values of `SELECT` clause and it has to be true for all but here it is not the case. He is not comparing a single value to all values of `tp` table rather if given `tp` has 4 records(`value`) then we need to list all `op` which has all those 4 records(`value`) or more. Let me know if I misundertood something.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, thanks, I've tried your approach, too (at least if I understood correctly), but unfortunately the query didn't complete in reasonable time.

Comment: to be fair you didn't stated you wanted to have query which gives the best performance nor you give anny information of the amount of records in the tables, indexing would help for sure..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, you are right. I have added record counts to the end of my question. And while my question is answered now, it unfortunately doesn't solve my problem because the suggested query is too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your tables name `ops` and `tps`.

```
SELECT 
    ops.op
FROM ops
INNER JOIN tps ON tps.value = ops.value 
WHERE tps.tp = 1
GROUP BY ops.op
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ops.value) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tps.value) FROM tps WHERE tps.tp = 1);  --- You can replace 1 with any tp value.
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this could work (unfortunately I can't confirm because the query is still running). All fields are indexed and this is what explains shows me: https://pastebin.com/nWtLwJxY . Is this expected to be this slow?

Comment: @mstrap, use `tps.tp = 1` in `WHERE clause` too, it will reduce the no of joins and improve performance. See the updated query.

Comment: Thanks! It's definitely better with the addition 'WHERE'-clause. Unfortunately it's still too slow (almost 2 minutes). I have added information on record counts to my question. My question is answered. Still, I would be thankful if you have any ideas on speed this up (no problem if parts of the query should better be performed in our code instead of in MySQL).

Comment: @mstrap, please share new output for `EXPLAIN` statement, we can definitely improve it based on indexes using in this query.

Comment: I've pasted the new explain plan at: https://pastebin.com/mMirtaXQ . This time, I have used the real names (to be sure I won't make any mistakes when translating to example names from my question). In case, you may find this confusing, I can translate it back to examples names. Also, please note that I have skipped '(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tps.value) FROM tps WHERE tps.tp = 1)' from the query because it's a constant which can easily be computed before the main query.

Comment: @mstrap, I am afraid, we are almost at a better state. MySQL already using the desired keys in both tables. Even we did make the result of `tp` as const. Now only an expert can help us to get better performance. BTW sometimes defragmenting keys also improves perfomance. It will clear all old, unwanted keys to make it faster.

Comment: OK, then I have to look for other options (maybe solve the problem in code instead of MySQL). Anyway, many thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help dude. :) Don't forget to vote up if not did already. :)